# How to properly delete a row using PHP & PDO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, delete-row

I looked up multiple ways to delete a specified row in PDO, and I am a beginner in learning PHP/PDO. I originally used Mysql_query and the like, but I am now told that it is bad practice to use. I have a script to delete a news post by id when the delete button is pressed. I converted it from the original MySQL code to PDO, but in doing so I fear I misread something and messed up. I'm just wondering if this is a "secure" method of doing this or if I should be using MySQLI and the like.

Below is my script, if you can help me get it working that would be great, but I am more interested in the correct and proper way to delete a row in PHP/PDO.

```
 <?php
    $dbh = connectDb(); 

    if( isset($_POST['delete']) )
    {
        if( isset( $_POST['id'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['id'] ) && $_POST['id'] > 0 )
        {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare( "DELETE FROM stats WHERE id =:id" );
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid ID";
        }
    }
    $stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id ASC');

    while($stmt = $rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo <<<_END
        <pre>
        Id: {$rows['id']}
        Title: {$rows['title']}
        Body: {$rows['body']}
        Date: {$rows['date']}
        </pre>
        <form action="rmposts.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$rows['id']}" />
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="DELETE NEWS" /></form>
    _END;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the value for `$id` ?

Comment: But you should get the posted form field using `$id=$_POST["id"]` before using it?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$row[0]" />` should be `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" />`

Comment: @SearchAndResQ OP use Heredoc, so he can not use `echo`. But yes, there is an error also in these lines: `$rows['id']` => `{$rows['id']}`

Comment: @fusion3k thanks, i don't anything about heredoc :(. Have just done some basic php coding (obviously :) )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you don't set properly the `$id` variable. You have to understand that the php script receive all form values (including the id to deleted) in `$_POST` variable: any other value previously loaded is not maintained when you reload the script.

So, you have to check for `$_POST['id']` and assigning its value to `$id` variable:

```
$dbh = connectDb(); 

if( isset($_POST['delete']) )
{
    if( isset( $_POST['id'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['id'] ) && $_POST['id'] > 0 )
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare( "DELETE FROM news WHERE id =:id" );
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        if( ! $stmt->rowCount() ) echo "Deletion failed";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ID must be a positive integer";
    }
}
```

First of all, we promote `if( isset($_POST['delete']) )` to a wrapper for the full delete code: there is no reason to prepare the query if it is not executed. Also, if `$_POST['delete']` is not set, it not means that deletion fails, but simply that deletion is not requested, so we remove the error alert.

Then, we check for `$_POST['id']` validity (exists, is numeric, is positive), we assign it to `$id` variable and now we perform the query: through `->rowCount()` we check the rows affected by the query and, if the result is 0, we display an error message.

---

#### Edit: additional errors:

Your query routine is wrong:

```
    $rows = dbh->query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id ASC');
#   └─┬─┘
#     └─────────┐
#             ┌─┴─┐
while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Change above first line in:

```
$stmt = dbh->query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id ASC');
```

Also your [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax is wrong: inside `<<<_END ... END` you have to wrap array names by square brackets: `{$rows['id']}`, `{$rows['title']}`, etc...

#### Carefully note:

While debugging code, **you have to check for errors:**

And, in the future, **don't forget to activate error checking** in our php code:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

With error checking, our original code produce this error:

Activate error reporting (`error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` at top of your script) and — if you got a 500 server error — look at your server error log: here you will see the detailed error, the file and the line in which error occurred.

Comment: Before writing the answer I have tested the code. What problem do you have now? What message is printed?

Comment: When you have a 500 syntax error you have to look at webserver log to see what happen and the line of error. `$rows = dbh->query` => `$rows = $dbh->query`

Comment: What error message do you have? So, all the script is not working, not only the deletion part.

Comment: `$rows` remains in `while($rows = $stmt`. You have to change only previous line.

Comment: Have you read my answer? “ if you got a 500 server error — look at your server error log”

Comment: have you changed `dbh->query` to `$dbh->query` ??

Comment: At least, show your line 42. have you see line 42? Can you see something weird in it?

Comment: Sorry, but you have to try to understand how to write code before asking. You have problems not only in above script. Also I suspect that code in your question is not code that generate errors, because in question's code there is not any `$rows` at line 32. Can you try to understand the error messages? I think they are self-explanatory: Constants are already defined, `$rows` is not defined (compare your actual code with my answer and with a bit of attention you can see the difference)...

Comment: Well done. But take a look at other errors: it is not safe ignoring errors. Also, if you compare (as suggested in previous comment) your while code with while code in answer you really can easy find the difference. And in the future, check your code step by step (not at the end): this will save a lot of time! Have a good day.